# Abstract Factory Design Pattern - C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have followed this nice article for ***Factory Design Pattern***:

http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-c-factory

I understand this example very well. Can you please make this same example for

***Abstract Factory Design Pattern*** ?

I want to understand the basic concept of ***Abstract Factory Design Pattern***.

Thanks

Comment: -1  This should be researched especially given the answer so far is just a link.

Answer (score 2):

A commom construction is a abstract factory that creates data access components, and you implements each factory specific for a database vendor or another repository system.

```
using System;
namespace DZoneArticles.FactoryDesignPattern
{
    public abstract class EmployeeFactory
    {
         public abstract Employee Create();
    }
    public class DBAFactory : EmployeeFactory
    {
         public override Employee Create() { return new DBA(); }
    }
    public class ManagerFactory : EmployeeFactory
    {
         public override Employee Create() { return new Manager(); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Abstract factory](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternAbstract.aspx) -- Not the same example, but easy to understand.

Comment: i need Abstract Factory Desgin Pattern by using the same example i have provided so that i can understand it better. You can modify the code / extend the code.

Comment: I know that the interface remains same. And those classes too. We can have Programmer and SeniorProgrammer under the category of DEVELOPER's and NetworkDBA and SQLServerDBA under the category of DBA's. Now i think so we can create factory classes based on this.

Answer (score 1):

Adaptation from "Applied Java Patterns":

```
 public interface IEmployee
 {
 }

 public class Developer : IEmployee
 {
 }

 public class Tester : IEmployee
 {
 }

 public interface IManager
 {
 }

 public class HRManager : IManager
 {
 }

 public class ProjectManager : IManager
 {
 }

 public interface IFactory()
 {
      IEmployee CreateEmployee();
      IManager CreateManager();
 }

 public class ConcreteFactory1 : IFactory
 {
      public IEmployee CreateEmployee()
      {
           return new Developer();
      }

      public IManager CreateManager()
      {
           return new HRManager();
      }
 }

 public class ConcreteFactory2 : IFactory
 {
      public IEmployee CreateEmployee()
      {
           return new Tester();
      }

      public IManager CreateManager()
      {
           return new ProjectManager();
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple example of Abstract Factory Design Pattern in C#:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

enum TYPE_OPERATION
{
    Design,
    Work
}

//Abstract Factory
abstract class AbstractFactory
{
    public static AbstractFactory PrepareOperation(TYPE_OPERATION type_operation)
    {
        switch (type_operation)
        {
            case TYPE_OPERATION.Design:
                return new DesignTeam();

            case TYPE_OPERATION.Work:
                return new WorkTeam();
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public abstract void PerformOperation();
}

class DesignTeam : AbstractFactory
{
    public override void PerformOperation()
    {
        Designers m = new Designers();
        m.Designing();
    }
}

class WorkTeam : AbstractFactory
{
    public override void PerformOperation()
    {
        Workers k = new Workers();
        k.Working();
    }
}

// The concrete class
class Designers
{
    public void Designing()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The Design Team has completed its work!");
    }
}

// The concrete class
class Workers 
{
    public  void Working()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The Work Team has finished its work!");
    }
}
public class Client
{   
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        AbstractFactory factory = AbstractFactory.PrepareOperation(TYPE_OPERATION.Design);
        factory.PerformOperation();

        factory = AbstractFactory.PrepareOperation(TYPE_OPERATION.Work);
        factory.PerformOperation();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
 }
/* output:
 The Design Team has completed its work!
 The Work Team has finished its work!
*/
```